# Sumar valor dinámico jquery + valor estático php en una tabla HTML

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, html5

Necesito sumar un valor dinámico obtenido con jQuery + un valor estático traído con php desde BD MySQL en una tabla HTML... en la primera fila me funciona, pero a partir de la segunda fila me sigue tomando el primer valor leído con php.

[image: Tabla HTML]

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
    <div class="container" style="padding: 50px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Nombre </th>
                        <th> Lunes </th>
                        <th> Martes </th>
                        <th> Miercoles </th>
                        <th> Jueves </th>
                        <th> Viernes </th>
                        <th> Puntaje Obtenido </th>
                        <th> Puntaje Acumulado </th>
                        <th> Puntaje Nuevo </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <!-- Número de filas según la cantidad de usuarios activos -->
                <?php while ($row = $query1 -> fetch_array()):?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="<?= $row['id']; ?>">
                            <td><?= $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
                            <!-- Número de columnas = 5 -->
                            <?php for ($i=1; $i<=5 ; $i++):?>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="puntos" id="puntos" required>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <!-- Listado de puntos por color traído de MySQL -->
                                        <?php                                                           
                                            while ($valor = $query2 -> fetch_array()) {
                                                $lista.= "<option value='".$valor['puntos']."'>".$valor['color']."</option>";
                                            }
                                            echo $lista;
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            <?php endfor;?>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Puntaje Obtenido (suma de puntos de toda la fila) -->
                                <input name="obtenido" id="obtenido" value="" readonly>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Puntaje Acumulado traído de MySQL -->
                                <input name="acumulado" id="acumulado" value="<?= $row["acumulado"]; ?>" readonly>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Puntaje Obtenido + Puntaje Acumulado -->
                                <input name="total" id="total" value="" readonly>
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>
                        <script>
                            /*Puntaje Obtenido*/
                            $("select").change(function(){
                                var i=0;
                                $(this).closest("tr").find("select").each(function(){
                                    if ( $(this).val() !== "" )
                                    i += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                                });
                                $(this).closest("tr").find("#obtenido").val(i);

                                /*Puntaje Nuevo (conserva el primer valor -16) es lo que necesito que cambie en cada fila*/
                                var j = 0;
                                $(this).closest("tr").find("select").each(function(){
                                    if ( $(this).val() !== "" )
                                    j += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                                    nuevo = parseInt($("#acumulado").val()) + parseInt(j);
                                });
                                $(this).closest("tr").find("#total").val(nuevo);
                            });
                        </script>
                    </tbody>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y estas son las tablas de MySQL:

[image: Usuarios]
[image: Colores]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el id tiene que ser unico en todo el DOM.  No puedes tener todos los inputs con el mismo id.  En lugar de eso usa clases asi:

```
<input name="acumulado" class="acumulado" value="<?= $row["acumulado"]; ?>" readonly>
```

Luego para obtener el valor harias esto:

```
nuevo = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find(".acumulado").val()) + parseInt(j);
```

Tienes que hacer algo parecido con los inputs `obtenido`.

Comment: Gracias por la orientación @alanfcm, funciona perfecto!!!