# JavaScript. error al sacar total solo me funciona con la primera fila

Tags: javascript

tengo un inconveniente para sacar el total, en la funcion **sacartotal** solo me **funciona con la primera fila**, en las demás no funciona, la tabla será una tabla dinámica, agradecería su ayuda, a continuación adjunto el código HTML y JavaScript.

```js
// funcion para vender por cantidad (mayor a 12 por docena).
// funciona gracias a esta comunidad. 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario); 
});
function validarFormulario(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    let cant_vm = parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant_vm").value );
    let cant_actual = document.getElementsByClassName("cant_actual");

    for(var i = 0; i < cant_actual.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(cant_actual[i].value) < cant_vm) {
         alert("Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a "+ cant_vm)
         cant_actual[i].focus()
         return 0; 
      }
    }
    this.submit(); 
}

// despues de modificar la cantidad. onchange
// llamanos la funcion sacartotal
function actualizar_total() {
  sacartotal();
}

// solo funciona con la primera fila
// sera una tabla dinaminca.
function sacartotal() {
    let prec = document.getElementsByClassName("prec")[0].value;
    let cant = parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant").value );
    let resul = document.getElementById("resul").value = prec*cant;
}
```

```html
<form action="echo.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
<table>
<tr>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Precio</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
    <!-- <td>Act. Cant.</td> -->
        <td>Total</td>
</tr>
 <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="TECLADO"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="50" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="cant" value="1" class="cant_actual" 
        onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="resul" value="50"></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="MOUSE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="30" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="cant" value="1" class="cant_actual"
        onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="resul" value="30"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="PARLANTE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="" value="80" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" id="cant" value="1" class="cant_actual"
         onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="resul" value="80"></td>
    </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>

<br>
<label>Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a </label>
<input type="text" value="12" id="cant_vm">
```

saludos amigos, tengo un inconveniente para sacar el total, en la funcion **sacartotal** solo me **funciona con la primera fila**, en las demás no funciona, la tabla será una tabla dinámica, agradecería su ayuda, a continuación adjunto el código HTML y JavaScript.

Comment: Es una muuuy mala idea tener elementos con ID repetido. Por ahí ya va mal la cosa.

Comment: Alfabravo por favor podrías ayudarme a resolverlo ?

Comment: Tal vez la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192239/sumar-valor-din%c3%a1mico-jquery-valor-est%c3%a1tico-php-en-una-tabla-html) _e incluso la misma pregunta_ te ayude a aclarar las dudas que tienes. No es exactamente tu caso, _ni tiene las mejores prácticas_, pero te puede orientar un poco. Aquí hay [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199288/contar-valores-en-columnas-de-una-tabla-html) que te puede orientar.

Answer (score -1):

Encontré la solución, a mi mismo problema, qui les comparto el código, por si alquilen lo necesita.

```js
// funcion para vender por cantidad (mayor a 12 por docena).
// funciona gracias a esta comunidad. 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario); 
});
function validarFormulario(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    let cant_vm = parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant_vm").value );
    let cant_actual = document.getElementsByClassName("cant_actual");

    for(var i = 0; i < cant_actual.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(cant_actual[i].value) < cant_vm) {
         alert("Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a "+ cant_vm)
         cant_actual[i].focus()
         return 0; 
      }
    }
    this.submit(); 
}

// despues de modificar la cantidad. onchange
// llamanos la funcion sacartotal
function actualizar_total() {
  sacartotal();
}

// solo funciona con la primera fila
// sera una tabla dinaminca.
function sacartotal() {
    var cant = document.querySelectorAll('.cant');
    var prec = document.querySelectorAll('.prec');
    var subtotals = document.querySelectorAll('.resul');

    for(var i = 0; i < cant.length; i++){ 
      subtotals[i].value = cant[i].value * prec[i].value;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="echo.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
<table>
<tr>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Precio</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
    <!-- <td>Act. Cant.</td> -->
        <td>Total</td>
</tr>
 <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="TECLADO"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="50" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" required class="cant_actual cant" 
        onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" class="resul"></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="MOUSE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="30" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" required class="cant_actual cant"
        onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" class="resul"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="PARLANTE"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" value="80" class="prec"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="" required class="cant_actual cant"
         onchange="actualizar_total()"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="" class="resul"></td>
    </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>

<br>
<label>Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a </label>
<input type="hidden" value="12" id="cant_vm">
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. La respuesta será de utilidad solamente si explicas qué cambios has hecho y por qué. Recuerda siempre que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código.

Comment: Si respondiste dos veces lo mismo a tu pregunta que hiciste dos veces, entonces la pregunta es la misma y esta duplicada. Igual tu respuesta no es buena, no explica nada de nada del problema.